# Getting information about a particular task_id

Tags: api, asana

I want to get the information like "created_at" , "completed" for a particular task id in asana. I used the following :
    https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/task_id  but it is giving the error message :  "assignee: Missing input" .

I also used https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/project_id/tasks?opt_fields=name,created_at,completed   to get tasks related to a particular project but I want
the information about a specific task.

So is there any way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're making a POST or PUT request. You should be making a GET request if you want to retrieve information.